# swift 2 error cannot assign to property "identifier" is a get only property in prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift

**i want to make a tradition segue which transfers' the content from the table view to the next view controller to which it is navigated. 
the code is something like:** Please help!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello from \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier = "ShowSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController
        {
            let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!)
            destination.viasegue = (cell?.textLabel?.text!)!
        }
    }
}
```

}

I declared the variables in the SecondViewController Class like:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var viasegue = ""
@IBOutlet weak var showlabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showlabel.text = viasegue

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

**There is an error Showing: Cannot assign to property: "Identifier is a get only property in the ViewController Class**

Comment: `if segue.identifier == "ShowSegue"` ... you need to use `==`

Comment: close as it is simple typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below.

```
if segue.identifier == "ShowSegue" {

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

            let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!)
            destination.viasegue = (cell?.textLabel?.text!)!

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You trying to assign to value of ShowSegue to segue.identifier (single =) use double == instead:

```
if segue.identifier == "ShowSegue" {
```

Comment: Awesome , how didn't i notice that small typo, the error msg  is not very helpful

Answer (score 2):

you should use `==` instead of `=` .

```
if segue.identifier = "ShowSegue" {
```